# tap interface not coming up

Tags: linux, interface, kernel, raw-ethernet

I decided to add a tap interface and use it in my code , but I am able to get its state UP.

```
sudo ip -f link tuntap add tap10 mode tap
sudo ip link set tap10 up
```

After this when I do "ip link"

```
tap10: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 500
link/ether 26:cc:d2:b4:37:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

state DOWN: How to get this state UP ? I am trying to send packets to it and nothing is received .

Answer (score 13):

It turns out that you need to have a proccess that uses your tap interface in order for it to be active.

This means that you need to write or use a program that connects to the interface file descriptor, then it will change its state to "RUNNING".

Comment: Curious Guy 007, can you accept the answer if it answered your question?