# Why does tap interface status always show as down through netlink (libnl)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, netlink

I have a network namespace named name1. 
I executed the command "ip netns exec name1 ip tuntap add mode tap name tap0".
I see the creation of tap0 through netlink message.
I executed "ip netns exec name1 ifconfig tap0 up".
I still see the interface status as "down" for tap0 in the netlink message.
But for the loopback interface in the same namespace, I see the status shown correctly through netlink.

I am using libnl cache manager to get the updates through netlink.

Any idea why the message is wrong only for tap interfaces?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tap interface not coming up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570906/tap-interface-not-coming-up)